# How to cycle through without it being random?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a method like so:

```
     function randomHighlights() {
        loops++;
        var newRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
        while (lastRandom == newRandom) {
          newRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
        }
        lastRandom = newRandom;
        var li = $('#u-' + newRandom);
        $('#home-grid-list li').random().addClass(function() {
          var liClass = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);;
          $('#home-grid-list li').removeClass('color-off');
          $('#home-grid-list li.' + liClass[0]).addClass('color-off');
          clearTimeout(timer);
        });
        $('#home-grid-list li').removeClass('text-on');
        timer = setTimeout(randomHighlights, 2500);
        if (loops == 20) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
          longHighlight();
        }
      }
```

It highlights 4 images at a time. The problem is I don't want it to be random anymore because there are only 3 different choices for it to be random and obviously it ends up picking the same block more than once creating a lag effect. Now I want to cycle through the `#home-grid-list` and highlight them cyclically. Any advice on how to do that?

**`longHighlight()` just highlights a random block of 4 pictures for longer than returns to this method.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Is this more what you had in mind?

JS:

```
var items = $('#home-grid-list').children('li');
var len = items.length;
var arr = [0,1,2,3];

window.setInterval(cycle,1000);

function cycle() {
    items.removeClass('highlight');
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    var temp = arr.shift();
    arr.push(((temp+4<len)?temp+4:temp+4-len));
    }
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        items.filter('#u-'+arr[i]).addClass('highlight');   
    }
}
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gjjq51n/1/).

---

Something like this?

JS:

```
var items = $('#home-grid-list').children('li');
var len = items.length;
var arr = [0,1,2,3];

window.setInterval(cycle,1000);

function cycle() {
    items.removeClass('highlight');
    var temp = arr.shift();
    arr.push(((temp+4<len)?temp+4:temp+4-len));
    console.log(arr);
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        items.eq(arr[i]).addClass('highlight');   
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gjjq51n/).

Comment: So that is great, but I select pretty much by id, like `<li id="u-1"> <li id="u-2"> <li id="u-3"> <li id="u-4">` and they would be the block selected but i don't get them in order every-time. Do you understand what I mean? `<li id="u-1"> <li id="u-5"> <li id="u-6"> <li id="u-4"><li id="u-7"> <li id="u-2"> <li id="u-3"> <li id="u-8">` and I only need the 1,2,3,4 to highlight then 5,6,7,8?

Comment: @TooTiredToDrink You mean you want them to be highlighted 4 at a time, and then the next set of 4, and so on?

Comment: @TooTiredToDrink Check the updated answer. See if that's close to what you want.

Comment: very nice almost here I need it. I can figure it out from here! thank you!